# Class method animatewithduration:position: not found

Tags: ios, animation

I am trying to move towards a sprite. But I am getting a warning: `class method animatewithduration:position: not found`. What am I doing wrong?

```
    CCSprite *train = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"train.png"];
    [train setScale:0.05];
    train.position = ccp(15, size.height/2);
    [self addChild:train];

    CCMoveTo *action = [CCMoveTo animationWithDuration: 2.3f    position:CGPointMake(200,400)];
    [train runAction:action];
```

Comment: Haven't used Cocos2D for years, but don't you mean `actionWithDuration:` ?

Comment: Yeah what version of Cocos2D?

Comment: I've got v2.1 of Cocos2D